# How to override the constructor in the base class?

Tags: c++

I'm making a game in C++. I have a player and enemy class that inherit my mob class. I would like my constructor in the enemy class to have a different constructor than my mob class, but it doesn't seem to work.

Mob.h

```
#pragma once

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class Mob
{
public:
     Mob();
    ~Mob();

    void update();
    void render();

protected:
    static sf::Sprite mSprite;

    static float mSpeed;
};
```

Mob.cpp

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "Enemy.h"
#include "Player.h"

Mob::Mob()
{

}

Mob::~Mob() {

}
```

Enemy.h

```
#pragma once

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "Mob.h"

class Enemy : public Mob
{
public:
    Enemy(sf::Sprite sprite);
    ~Enemy();

    void update(float delta, Player player);
    void render(sf::RenderWindow& window);
};
```

Enemy.cpp

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "Enemy.h"
#include "Player.h"

Enemy::Enemy(sf::Sprite sprite)
{
    mSprite = sprite;

    mSpeed = 150.0f;
}

Enemy::~Enemy() {

}

void Enemy::update(float delta, Player player) {

}

void Enemy::render(sf::RenderWindow& window) {
    window.draw(mSprite);
}
```

Player.h

```
#pragma once

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "Mob.h"

class Player : public Mob
{
public:
    Player(sf::Sprite sprite);
    ~Player();

    void update(float delta);
    void render(sf::RenderWindow& window);
};
```

Player.cpp

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "Player.h"

Player::Player(sf::Sprite sprite)
{
    mSprite = sprite;

    mSpeed = 150.0f;
}

Player::~Player() {

}

void Player::update(float delta) {

    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W))
    {
        mSprite.move(0, -mSpeed * delta);
    }
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A))
    {
        mSprite.move(-mSpeed * delta, 0);
    }
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::S))
    {
        mSprite.move(0, mSpeed * delta);
    }
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D))
    {
        mSprite.move(mSpeed * delta, 0);
    }
}

void Player::render(sf::RenderWindow& window) {
    window.draw(mSprite);
}
```

Forgot to add my errors:

```
Error   3   error C2511: 'void Enemy::update(float,Player)' : overloaded member function not found in 'Enemy'   c:\dev\c++\sven\sven\enemy.cpp  16  1   Sven
Error   1   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Player' c:\dev\c++\sven\sven\enemy.h    12  1   Sven
Error   2   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Player' c:\dev\c++\sven\sven\enemy.h    12  1   Sven
```

Comment: How does it not seem to work?

Comment: "It doesn't seem to work", please clarify.

Comment: Sorry, edited my post.

Comment: You can *overload* a constructor, not override, which you do for `virtual` functions. Constructors may not even be `virtual`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Enemy.h you have `void update(float delta, Player player);`.  How does the compiler know what a play is?  It cant since you never included the player.h file in enemy.h.  You have to options to fix this you can either include player.h or you could [forward declare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/c-forward-declaration) player and change the function to take a pointer to a player.